# Is there a workaround to make class operators work for built-in types

Tags: delphi, operator-overloading

I can use class operators for strings using an intermediate holding record.
So that I can so implicit conversion of built-in types.

```
program TestNewStringHelper; 
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  System.SysUtils;
type
  TStringRecord = record
  private
    Data: string;
  public
    class operator Implicit(const a: TStringRecord): Integer; inline;
    class operator Implicit(const a: string): TStringRecord; inline;
  end;

{ TStringRecord }

class operator TStringRecord.Implicit(const a: string): TStringRecord;
begin
  pointer(Result.Data):= pointer(a);
end;

class operator TStringRecord.Implicit(const a: TStringRecord): Integer;
begin
  Result:= StrToInt(a.Data);
end;

var
  input: TStringRecord;
  output: integer;

begin
  input:= '42';
  output:= input;
  WriteLn(IntToStr(output));
  ReadLn;
end.
```

I would like to do something like instead:

```
var
  input: string;
  output: integer;

begin
  input:= '42';
  output:= input;  //Class operator magic
  WriteLn(IntToStr(output));
  ReadLn;
end.
```

According to the online help:

> Note: Class and record helpers do not support operator overloading.

and http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=72253

Is there a workaround to achieve implicit conversion of built-in types without using an intermediary type?

Comment: Do you want to turn strongly typed Delphi into some crazy scripting language? :)

Comment: `MyDateTime:= 'Twenty past midday'`;

Comment: It sounds like a really bad idea... trying to make any language act more like VB6 just seems wrong.

Comment: @J, Relax, I was planning nothing of the sort. I just want to use `operator overloading` on built-in types. Mainly for string and array manipulation. The example is just to show the concept.

Comment: Anyway same arguments where exchanged when operator overloading was introduced and from what I can see people have mostly used it to produce beautiful concise and clear code.

Comment: That is true but still you have to be careful. If you could add operator overloading on existing types through helpers that could cause total havoc. Imagine someone introduces a type helper in some unit you are using and adds some operator overloads. That will suddenly change all your behavior. Hardly a good thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Record and class helpers are the only way to extend the method scope for existing types. And helpers do not admit operator overloading.

The only point at which you can define overloading operators is whilst defining the type.